I was coding the other day when it occurred to me that it could be possible to program Bernoulli numbers. Is this possible, and how so?
I wanted to try and get the first 20 Bernoulli numbers using Python. Recently, I've been researching about Ada Lovelace, and Note G was an algorithm for the Analytical Engine to compute Bernoulli numbers, so I was wondering if I could do that with Python?
Bernoulli numbers are a sequence of rational numbers that are special values of the Bernoulli polynomials. (I got the recursive definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Definitions.)
I'm just beginning in Python so I am familiar with functions, strings, integers, if/elif/else, for loops, nested loops, variables, lists and dictionaries.

Can you write down the definition of Bernoulli numbers here? This will help qualify your question according to the community guidelines. As well, maybe show what you know in terms of coding say constants, variables, arrays, strings, functions, etc.

I wrote this a while ago and it seems to provide the correct Bernoulli numbers $B_k$ for $k \in \{1, \dots, 20\}$. Its based on a recursion that you can find on the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).
#used to get combinations
import scipy.special
#return the k-th Bernoulli number, defined by
# z/(1 - e^z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} B_k/k! * z^k
    #multiplying by 1 - e^z and comparing coefficients gives the recursion relation that is used here to compute B_k
    bernoulli_dict = {0 : 1, 1 : -1/2}
    
    def bernoulli(k):
        if k in bernoulli_dict:
            return bernoulli_dict[k]
        elif k % 2 == 1: #we already check for k = 1 in previous condition
            return 0
        else:
            s = 0
            for n in range(0, k // 2):
                s += bernoulli(2 * n) * scipy.special.comb(k + 1, 2 * n)
            s *= -1/(k + 1)
            s += 1/2
            bernoulli_dict[k] = s
            return s


I'm wondering why my answer has been downvoted...
